# Get Customer ID in template file

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-2.2.5

I'm building a module where it needs the Customer ID to filter some data in a table.

I currently have my Block class set up like this:

```
namespace TreyBake\Garage\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Garage extends Template
{
    protected $garageCollectionFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \TreyBake\Garage\Model\ResourceModel\Garage\CollectionFactory $garageCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->garageCollectionFactory = $garageCollectionFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSesssion;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getGarageCollection()
    {
        return $this->garageCollectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function getCustomerID()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }
}
```

and I try to echo it out in my template file like this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$collection = $this->getGarageCollection();
$collectionCount = count($collection);

echo $this->getCustomerID();
```

but this outputs nothing:
[image]

weirder yet, if I remove that `echo $this->getCustomerID();` my other content loads e.g. there's an if statement based on `$collectionCount` - this outputs the correct string. When the echo is there it doesn't output anything (as displayed in the img above).

What am I doing wrong?

if you need more code/files - lemme know.

**Edit:**

I've adjusted my Block code to this:

```
public function getCustomerID()
{
    $customer = $this->customerSession->create();
    return $customer->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

still nothing displayed :S

Comment: Please check your system.log or exception.log and tell me any error?

Comment: @RohanHapani nothing in there (relating to the page anyways) :s

Comment: Instead of print echo in file. check customer id by log file. Try to check it. Still, if you'll get blank then inform here.

Comment: @RohanHapani ok... how does one do this? :)

Comment: Remove echo and add this code => $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info($this->getCustomerID());

Go to var/log folder and check test.log file

Comment: @RohanHapani nothing gets outputted to the file :/

Comment: @RohanHapani I think the issue is within the Block class -removing all calls of `$this->getCustomerID()` in my template file, still displays nothing. Think the Block class is incorrect somehow. ..

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: @RohanHapani it didn't no :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Factory Method :

```
protected $_customerSessionFactory;

public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    \TreyBake\Garage\Model\ResourceModel\Garage\CollectionFactory $garageCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
)
{
    $this->garageCollectionFactory = $garageCollectionFactory;
    $this->_customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;

    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCustomerID()
{
    return $this->_customerSessionFactory->create();
}
```

and add use code in template file :

```
echo $block->getCustomerID()->getCustomer()->getId();
```

**Remove genereated and flush cache.**

Comment: it does work! You had a typo in your variable name for getCustomerID() and I just copied + pasted instead of reading it

Comment: it's working fine using "Factory Method".